# activeadmin conflict with i18n-active_record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, rails-i18n

Using `i18n-active_record` for translations, it works fine. But it giving issues on activeadmin. Activeadmin not displaying any text and showing keys with translation missing text.

I want `activeadmin` to work without `i18n-active_record`
[image]

Comment: can you check the hierarchy of the message which you want to display.

Comment: You meant work *with* i18n-active_record, right?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48368778/i18n-active-record-backend-using-railsadmin

Comment: @PiersC yes ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know who might have tested this. If you submit a GitHub issue with a *simple working example* someone may look at it.